# acer aspire touchpad gestures not working

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, acer, multi-touch, aspire

When I try to load the psmouse module I get:

```
$ /sbin/rmmod psmouse
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:793 kmod_module_remove_module() could not remove 'psmouse': Operation not permitted
rmmod: ERROR: could not remove module psmouse: Operation not permitted
$ /sbin/modprobe psmouse
```

I tried `/sbin/rmmod psmouse` and `/sbin/modprobe psmouse` but the above result came out. AMD processor(64 bit) is installed in the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo` to load and unload kernel modules:

```
$ sudo rmmod psmouse
$ sudo modprobe psmouse
```